# what is the event that vim ctrl_w trigger

Tags: vim, window

I fail to inactivate cursorline when I use `ctrl_w ctrl_w` or something like that to switch window using :

```
au BufLeave * setlocal nocursorline
```

The manual saying :

```
BufLeave        Before leaving to another buffer.  Also when
                leaving or closing the current window and the
                new current window is not for the same buffer.
                Not used for ":qa" or ":q" when exiting Vim.
```

So, isn't the BufLeave event show fire when using `ctrl_w ctrl_w`?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your `autocmd` works fine for me, but be aware that it's triggered only when *leaving the buffer*. If both windows point to the same buffer, you're *not* leaving the buffer, you're just switching to a different view on the buffer.

We can verify this by using:

```
au BufLeave * echoerr 'BufLeave triggered!'
```

and then checking `:messages` to be sure.

In this case, you probably want to use the [`WinLeave`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#WinLeave) autocmd:

```
au WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured it out the reason why didn't it work is the plugin MiniBufExpl I installed. I just simply installed it, didn't dig much into it, I'm not sure if I can find out which part of that plugin effect the BufLeave, or how to make them work together. But once I did it, I will update this post to help people who have the same problem like me, just like what you did, Thank you very much!

Comment: @cyl19910101 It's working fine when I'm using [minibufexplorer++](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3239); note that [minibufexpl.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159) hasn't been updated in 12 years (!) so you probably don't want to use that...

Comment: Actually I was using this one : https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim, which happens to be the recommend replacement of minibufexplorer++ in minibufexplorer++ homepage, not the old one. Is the fholgado/minibufexpl.vim not works well for you?

Comment: @cyl19910101 Ah, the replacement has its own replacement now, which is named the same as the thing that the second plugin replaced :-/ This is confusing :-/